# A question about adding matrices

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry

If I have two square matrices with different size ($A$ and $B$) one of them in affine space ($A$ in n-dimention) and the another in projective space ($B$ in (n+1)-dimention).and if the firt row and the first column of matrix $B$ have zero elements. can I adde $A$ and the submatrix of $B$ wich has  n-dimention (I mean the first minor of matix $B$)

Comment: You can, but the problem is: what do you want to represent by this addition?

Comment: I want to change some elements of the matrix  A to change its rank. and the matrix B wich I used in projective space and has the above qualities.